# Insert/delete/retrieve elements of an array across threads without using globals

Tags: python

This might be a silly question, but what's the best way to keep insert/delete/retrieve elements of an array in a multi-threaded Python application, but not keep the array global or assign an entire thread to keep track of the changes to that single array? It feels tiresome to pass the array to each function I use.

Comment: Well, that's the choice: To have it available in F1..Fn, you either need to pass it to every F, or put it into a scope that's available to all F.

Comment: Please elaborate what kind of "tracking" you want to perform. Please also explain why you can't use global variables.

Comment: global variables just don't feel appropriate in this case, although I might be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use globals, maybe you can use Qt's QThread class. You can use signals to access to the thread.